# URL identifier and URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

In iOS you can set up URL scheme so other apps can launch you or pass data to you.  What's the URL Identifier for? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere other than when you specify URL Schemes.

Also, what happen when there is duplicate URL schemes on the phone?

Comment: Where are you seeing a reference to "URL Identifier"?

Comment: See [Multiple apps with the same URL Scheme - iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130442/multiple-apps-with-the-same-url-scheme-ios?rq=1) for your 2nd question.

Comment: @rmaddy Look at URL Types section in Info tab in Xcode.  In raw Info.plist it maps to CFBundleURLName.

Comment: In our case, we there is no for the Identifier. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27631275/4390461

Answer (score 18):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) they don't give much info about the identifier and why it is needed or where it is used. They only say that it should be unique:

> A string containing the abstract name of the URL scheme. To ensure uniqueness, it is recommended that you specify a reverse-DNS style of identifier, for example, com.acme.myscheme.
>   The string you specify is also used as a key in your app’s InfoPlist.strings file. The value of the key is the human-readable scheme name.

Also if more than one app specify the same url scheme, then the outcome is unpredictable:

> Note: If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme.

The experience taught me that the app who first registered that scheme will be opened, but **this may be wrong.**

Comment: **Note:** If you look at the `info.plist`, you'll notice that the **Identifier** maps to **URL identifier** or **CFBundleURLName**.

Comment: In practice when I have two apps with the same URL scheme (a lite and pro version of the same app) it ignores this field, perhaps going to the first installed.