# iOS: Adding my app to list of applications, when a shared location is opened in Whatsapp

Tags: ios, location, whatsapp, url-scheme

When Whatsapp receives a location and the user taps on it, a menu is opened, where the user can choose from several apps to open the location.
We would like to have our app included in the list as well.

[image]

We added geo: url-scheme to our plist.info, but this doesn't work here. Any idea, what url-scheme or deep-link whatsapp is using here, which we need to register our app for?

Comment: I suspect those two choices are coded in WhatsApp.

Comment: No, on one of our devices we installed HereWeGo App, and now this app is also in that list.

Comment: They could be using url schemes to detect the installed navigation app from a list of the most common/popular apps

Comment: Yes, but which url-scheme?

Comment: Each application has its own url scheme that they need to check for and add. There is no "generic" directions url scheme

Comment: Yes, that is actually the question..

Comment: What I am saying is that you can register any url scheme you like `tomsGroovyNavApp:` or whatever, but WhatsApp need to add that to their code before it becomes an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special or magic URL scheme that you can register for your app to make it appear in WhatsApp.  WhatsApp has a list of URL schemes that it checks for common/popular navigation apps.

You can register any url scheme you like in your app, the trick would be getting WhatsApp to add it to their app.

This screenshot shows the queried url schemes from WhatsApp's `info.plist`:

[image]

You can see that it includes Google Maps and Here maps.

Comment: This also applies:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130442/multiple-apps-with-the-same-url-scheme-ios